# eclipse maven deploy war to nexus OSS Access denied Error code 401, Unauthorized

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

I want to upload the deployed war file from maven in eclipse to nexus OSS, but I get an error message.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project xxx: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.xxx.xxx:xxx:war:5.2.0 from/to nexus (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/): Access denied to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/xxx/xxx/xxx/5.2.0/xxx-5.2.0.war. Error code 401, Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

With the same configuration (`pom.xml` and `settings.xml`) I deploy a jar file and it works.

The difference both of them are file type and file size.
The one is a war file with 80mb and the other is a jar file with only 400kb.

Does someone have ideas, how to solve this? are there configuration, those I miss? It was not happen 1 week ago. I don't change anything, only update the eclipse version from 2019 to 2020.

Thank you

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project xxx: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.xxx.xxx:xxx:war:5.2.0 from/to nexus (http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/): Access denied to http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/xxx/xxx/xxx/5.2.0/xxx-5.2.0.war. Error code 401, Unauthorized
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.xxx.xxx:xxx:war:5.2.0 from/to nexus (http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/): Access denied to http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/xxx/xxx/xxx/5.2.0/xxx-5.2.0.war. Error code 401, Unauthorized
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.xxx.xxx:xxx:war:5.2.0 from/to nexus (http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/): Access denied to http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/xxx/xxx/xxx/5.2.0/xxx-5.2.0.war. Error code 401, Unauthorized
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.AbstractDeployMojo.deploy(AbstractDeployMojo.java:167)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:157)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.xxx.xxx:xxx:war:5.2.0 from/to nexus (http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/): Access denied to http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/xxx/xxx/xxx/5.2.0/xxx-5.2.0.war. Error code 401, Unauthorized
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:386)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:142)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact com.xxx.xxx:xxx:war:5.2.0 from/to nexus (http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/): Access denied to http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/xxx/xxx/xxx/5.2.0/xxx-5.2.0.war. Error code 401, Unauthorized
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:889)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$PutTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:732)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.put(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:373)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:295)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: io.takari.aether.connector.AuthorizationException: Access denied to http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/com/xxx/xxx/xxx/5.2.0/xxx-5.2.0.war. Error code 401, Unauthorized
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.handleResponseCode(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:397)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.access$8(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:391)
    at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$PutTask.run(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:703)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxxxx</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>xxx xxx Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <url>http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>Nexus OSS Internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>Nexus OSS Internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:8081/repository/maven-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>deploy</defaultGoal>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

setting.xml

```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>Z:/maven/repository</localRepository>

  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>
  <proxies>
  </proxies>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
  </mirrors>

  <profiles>
  </profiles>

</settings>
```

Comment: Best is you install a command line Maven, close Eclipse and then try to deploy both the jar and the war again. Then tell us which errors you got.

Comment: I tried your advice and it works. I use, `mvn deploy`. What is the difference both of them?  How to solve this in eclipse? Thank you.

Comment: Usually, the difference must be somewhere in the settings.xml or the Maven version.

Comment: Make deployments to a repository on plain command line as JF Meier already suggested and the problem is related to your `settings.xml` and the definition in distributionManagment in your pom file which results in `Error code 401, Unauthorized`...please show pom.xml and settings.xml (of course username/password replaced with `*`)...

Comment: I added the pom.xml and settings.xml files. The both files use to deploy the jar file.

Comment: Have you double checked in your eclipse maven settings that you are actually using the settings.xml file reported in your question? The error message suggests you're not (or that the credentials are wrong)

Answer (score 4):

I have got the same problem and have been confused for weeks. I found this problem was occurred since Eclipse version 202003. Use same configs with V201912 or just deploy with CMD is fine.

I think it's a problem of eclipse's embedded Maven;

- in V201912 it is 3.6.3/1.14.0.20191209-1923
- in V202006 it is 3.6.3/1.16.0.20200610-1735.

Change to use an recently outer Maven artifacts 3.6.3 in V202006 is OK. So since I have dozens of workspaces I could only to use V201912 for now.

The eclipse-202009 will require java11 and dosen't support java8 any more, so, we will endure the problem forever?

Answer (score 4):

a problem with Aether connector in okhttp.
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=562847
https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/issues/250

So  2 workaounds:

- Use an external Maven runtime in the Launch Configuration instead of embedded one (so aether is not included)
- Set `-Daether.connector.basic.threads=1` in the launch configuration.

Comment: It sucks that situation has not been any improving up to now.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the m2e plugin, includes:

1. m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse
2. m2e - slf4j over logback logging

then use eclipse 2019-12 release site and install these two plugin is an easy way to fix it.