# Acces denied deploying artifact to Azure Artifacts using STS4

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, spring-tool-suite, azure-artifacts

I have a problem using STS4 deploying artifacts to Azure Artifacts. Using the same config files, I can deploy the artifacts using STS3. I do not modify anything and I cannot deploy anything to Azure, I always receive Access denied error.

My maven settings.xml (working with STS3) :

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
 <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
  <servers>

    <server>
      <id>[FEED_NAME]</id>
      <username>[USER_NAME]</username>
      <password>[PERSONAL_TOKEN]</password>
    </server>

</servers>
</settings>
```

and the pom.xml distributionmanagement

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>[FEED_NAME]</id>
            <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[ORGANIZATION]/[PROJECT]/_packaging/[FEED]/maven/v1</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

And the pom properties:

```
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
```

I have seen that the maven installation versions are different from STS3 to STS4. In STS4 in settings>Maven>Installations, I can see in Embedded `3.6.3/1.16.0.20200610-1735`and in STS3 `3.6.3/1.14.0.20191209-1923`but I do not know how to deal with that.

Any idea?

Thank you!!

Comment: Does it work when you run the Maven build from the command line instead of using the IDE? And if that works, what happens if you configure your local Maven installation to be used inside of the IDE instead of the embedded version? You can configure that in the `Preferences -> Maven -> Installations`.

Comment: Share the detailed error log in your question and the PERSONAL_TOKEN you provided have permission to access the feed?

Comment: I assume the preceding comment is just missing a word, but DO NOT share your PAT with anyone anywhere at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this.
Be aware that the feed can be set up as Organization or Project feed, so it makes a difference in the url e.g.:
`<url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[ORGANIZATION]/[PROJECT]/_packaging/[FEED]/maven/v1</url>` or `<url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/[ORGANIZATION]/_packaging/[FEED]/maven/v1</url>`

Also, the [USER_NAME] should be [ORGANIZATION] in your settings.xml.

Also, if you are using eclipse, then the built in Maven has an issue uploading jar files.  See answer here: [Maven Bintray distribution in Eclipse is not uploading jar files. Error code 401 (Unauthorized) but only for jar packaging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006644/maven-bintray-distribution-in-eclipse-is-not-uploading-jar-files-error-code-401)

Using an external Maven source solved the problem for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31458844)