# Why am i getting getting 401 unauthorized in nexus RELEASES repo while executing the 'deploy' command but not in SNAPSHOTS?

Tags: maven, repository, pom.xml, nexus

I have created the following 2 browz private repositories in Sonatype Nexus Repository OSS 3.53.1.-01:

```
 1. browz-dev-releases (type is maven hosted, disable redeploy)
 2. browz-dev-snapshots (type is maven hosted, allow redeploy)
 3. browz-dev-repos-group (type is a group where I have added browz-dev-releases, browz-dev-snapshots, and maven-public)
```

I am using Maven-3.9.1 and my Global and User maven settings.xml file is pointed to ${MAVEN_HOME}/conf/settings.xml. I have already entered below server entries:

```
    <server>
        <id>browz-dev-releases</id>
        <username>USER</username>
        <password>PASS</password>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>browz-dev-snapshots</id>
        <username>USER</username>
        <password>pass</password>
    </server>
```

Also, I have commented on this part in settings.xml:

```
  <!-- 
    <mirror>
      <id>maven-default-http-blocker</id>
      <mirrorOf>external:http:*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Pseudo repository to mirror external repositories initially using HTTP.</name>
      <url>http://0.0.0.0/</url>
      <blocked>true</blocked>
    </mirror>
  -->
```

And added this part in :

```
    <mirror> 
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf> 
      <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/browz-dev-repos-group/</url>
    </mirror>
```

Finally, I have following  define in settings.xml:

```
    <profile>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/browz-dev-repos-group/</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/browz-dev-repos-group/</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
```

and added this in  section of settings.xml:

```
     <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

I have the following entry in Project's POM.XML:

```
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>browz-dev-releases</id>
            <name>Dev Releases Repostiory</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/browz-dev-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>browz-dev-snapshots</id>
            <name>Dev Snapshots Repostiory</name>
            <url>http://localhost:8081/repository/browz-dev-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        
    </distributionManagement>
```

So, whenever I run the maven 'deploy' command to deploy the artifact to the repository if the artifact id contains "-SNAPSHOT" in the jar version then it successfully deploys to the browz-dev-snapshots repository but when I try to deploy the same jar by removing the "-SNAPSHOT" from the version, it gives me the following error:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy- 
    plugin:3.1.1:deploy(default-deploy)on project browz-framework: Failed to deploy artifacts: 
    Could not transfer artifact com.browz:browz-framework:jar:1.0.0 from/to browz-dev-releases 
    (http://localhost:8081/repository/browz-dev-releases/): Access denied to 
    http://localhost:8081/repository/browz-dev-releases/com/brwoz/browz-framework/1.0.0/browz- 
    framework-1.0.0.jar. Error code 401, Unauthorized[m ->[Help 1]
```

NOTE: The Nexus repository user that I am using to authenticate has an nx-admin role. I am just not able to understand why am i not able to deploy to the RELEASES repository but there is no issue deploying to the SNAPSHOTS repository with the same user and password.

If someone could guide me to the right path, I will be grateful to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the solution from the below thread and it works:
Adding -Daether.connector.basic.threads=1 maven command while running the 'deploy' command

[eclipse maven deploy war to nexus OSS Access denied Error code 401, Unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61536737/eclipse-maven-deploy-war-to-nexus-oss-access-denied-error-code-401-unauthorized)